# Comparing permanent and ad hoc views

Tags: view, couchdb, mapreduce

I need to reassure that I have a correct understanding of the difference for permanent and ad hoc views.

- Permanent views are stored in the
  _design document and computed upon being queried the first time, later
  changes to documents will result in
  changing the related documents in the
  stored B tree file for that view.
- Ad hoc views are calculated completely every time for the complete database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

just found the Solution in the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views).

I got it right.